# Intersection over union on non rectangular quadrilaterals

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection

I am working on the problem of parking space detection. To detect empty parking space I am using intersection over union. But, parking spaces aren't always rectangular. So, I have made a labeling tool that can draw polygons of various shapes. Now, I want to know if there is any python library that provides IOU functionality? If not is there any alternative?

[image]

Comment: So you want to calculate the IoU of two polygons as a kind of boxes I guess right?

Comment: @denis_lor yes. One box will be a square from Mask RCNN model and other will be a non-rectangular polygon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use the [`shapely`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) Python library:

```
from shapely.geometry import box, Polygon

# Define Each polygon 
pol1_xy = [[130, 27], [129.52, 27], [129.45, 27.1], [130.13, 26]]
pol2_xy = [[30, 27.200001], [129.52, 27.34], [129.45, 27.1], [130.13, 26.950001]]
polygon1_shape = Polygon(pol1_xy)
polygon2_shape = Polygon(pol2_xy)

# Calculate Intersection and union, and tne IOU
polygon_intersection = polygon1_shape.intersection(polygon2_shape).area
polygon_union = polygon1_shape.union(polygon2_shape).area
IOU = polygon_intersection / polygon_union
```

Comment: Do order of vertices matter?

Comment: it does not, as long as you list them clockwise or counter-clockwise in both cases

Answer (score 6):

There is a slight improvement that can be made to [ibarrond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58435475/12808884).  Finding the union of our two quadrilaterals is a costly operation.  Instead, we can find the area of the union by first adding the areas of both quadrilaterals.  This will over-count the area where the quadrilaterals overlap, but we can correct this by subtracting the area of the intersect, which we already calculated:

```
def IOU(pol1_xy, pol2_xy):
    # Define each polygon
    polygon1_shape = Polygon(pol1_xy)
    polygon2_shape = Polygon(pol2_xy)

    # Calculate intersection and union, and the IOU
    polygon_intersection = polygon1_shape.intersection(polygon2_shape).area
    polygon_union = polygon1_shape.area + polygon2_shape.area - polygon_intersection
    return polygon_intersection / polygon_union
```

The following code verifies that this improvement gives the same result, and then it times both versions.  Function `IOU1` contain's ibarrond's code, and function `IOU2` contains the improvement.

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from timeit import timeit

def IOU1(pol1_xy, pol2_xy):
    # Define each polygon
    polygon1_shape = Polygon(pol1_xy)
    polygon2_shape = Polygon(pol2_xy)

    # Calculate intersection and union, and the IOU
    polygon_intersection = polygon1_shape.intersection(polygon2_shape).area
    polygon_union = polygon1_shape.union(polygon2_shape).area
    return polygon_intersection / polygon_union

def IOU2(pol1_xy, pol2_xy):
    # Define each polygon
    polygon1_shape = Polygon(pol1_xy)
    polygon2_shape = Polygon(pol2_xy)

    # Calculate intersection and union, and tne IOU
    polygon_intersection = polygon1_shape.intersection(polygon2_shape).area
    polygon_union = polygon1_shape.area + polygon2_shape.area - polygon_intersection
    return polygon_intersection / polygon_union

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Define test coordinates:
    pol1_xy = [[130, 27], [129.52, 27], [129.45, 27.1], [130.13, 26]]
    pol2_xy = [[30, 27.200001], [129.52, 27.34], [129.45, 27.1], [130.13, 26.950001]]

    # Test that results are the same (except for minor rounding differences):
    assert abs(IOU1(pol1_xy, pol2_xy) - IOU2(pol1_xy, pol2_xy)) < 1e-16

    # Determine speeds of both functions:
    t1=timeit('IOU1(pol1_xy, pol2_xy)', number=100000,
              setup='from __main__ import IOU1, pol1_xy, pol2_xy')
    t2=timeit('IOU2(pol1_xy, pol2_xy)', number=100000,
              setup='from __main__ import IOU2, pol1_xy, pol2_xy')
    print('time for IOU1:  %s' %t1)
    print('time for IOU2:  %s' %t2)
```

Here's the result I obtained:

```
time for IOU1:  20.0208661
time for IOU2:  11.0288122
```

Note that the exact times will vary based on the hardware and the current background activity.